# Reserved parking for women in Germany

Tags: germany, automobiles

I've seen in several places in Germany that there are parking places which are reserved for women, in one such parking garage there was a sign saying that they are reserved due to *"safety reasons"*.

What is the reason that such parking places exist?

How is it (if at all) enforced?

Comment: Note that there are also two parking spaces [reserved for men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men%27s_parking_space) in Germany.

Comment: Those are but a joke, though :)

Comment: @Heinzi I'm actually a bit amazed at that.  Even the mayor publically suggesting that women can't park a car into a tricky spot without crashing into things... even as a joke I thought you couldn't get away with that sort of talk these days, especially in Europe, and doubly so in a country with such spectacular female driving role models as Sabine Schmitz!  WTF.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The main reason that women parking places exist is that parking areas are often considered as creepy. At some time they are completely deserted so you hear only the deep humming of the fluorescent tubes, every step (with high heels) announces loudly your presence (and that you are a woman, by the way), there is often bad lighting, few exits and both cars and the pillars are allowing people (in your vivid fantasy) to watch you without being seen. In short, eerie, scary, sinister.

It depends on the parking area if there are any legal means to enforce the reservation for women.

Once the owner admits that the StVO (the German road law) is valid (This is automatically the case if there are no effective borders to prevent access in contrast to e.g. multi-storey car parks), the owner cannot prohibit the usage by men.  But if the owner has their own terms (as being said, all multi-storey car parks or workplaces with their own parking places) the current interpretation of the law permits the owner to exclusively reserve places for women and according to a decision in 2011 *(LAG Rheinland-Pfalz, 2011-09-29 10 Sa 314/11)* it does not discriminate against men.

The current state is that is not really enforced, but culturally accepted to give women a more secure feeling. These places are very near to the entrance, have good lighting and camera supervision. It is really more about a *secure feeling*, there is no statistical indication that attacks are prevented by those places nor that even attacks in parking houses are more common than in other places.

The actual usage is that it is impolite to use them as men if there are free places left, but once the places are full, they will be used, too.

Comment: Neon tubes? Are parking lots in Germany lit by Neon? Maybe they are [Fluorescent tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp), or perhaps some sort of [sodium vapor lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-vapor_lamp) or [mercury-vapor lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-vapor_lamp)?

Comment: @Johnny they are Fluorescent tubes but in German, it is common to refer to them as "neon tubes".

Comment: What happens if a man parks there when it's full, but when he's about to leave there are lots of other spaces empty? Do people look down on him? :)

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't think so. At least I wouldn't. It is far more rude in my opinion to block a parking spot for the handicapped. If you do that I will despise you.

Comment: @Ian but isn't that also illegal by law, rather than terms of the parkhouse?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam I think so, but I see it much to often at the supermarket. How can you enforce that if people are only there for 15 minutes?

Comment: @Ian At supermarkets, it'll be hard since there generally is free parking and therefore no parking guards or anything. However, here in the Netherlands, in town, where you have to pay for parking at certain places, there will be controls and you can expect a hefty fine 
(150 euros) for parking in a handicap spot.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam German supermarkets do not have general free parking. In most cases you are only allowed to park there if you are using the supermarket. It happens (quite rarely I have to admit) that the supermarkt owner calls the police and all "illegal" parking cars are hauled of. However, this happens primarily on sundays - because during the week it is hard to check wether the owner of the car is "using" the supermarket or not.

Comment: The StVO does not automatically apply if there are no effective borders to prevent access. Maybe you confuse that with the StVZO and its successors, which define who is allowed to drive (driving permits etc.)

Comment: @Johnny Thanks for pointing that out, I corrected it. /Mehrdad No. /Jarko As I said, women's parking areas are not legally enforced in contrast to handicapped areas (Like in the Netherlands, the car can and will be immediately towed away, the fine is 35€). If you own the spot, you can restrict access at will., else apart from being handicapped there are no law violated. /Gnusper Unfortunately Aldi, Edeka and Rewe are now much stricter with towing because they outsourced it to private firms. /glglgl No, I mean the StVO, never seen a sign with *Hier gilt die StVO* ?

Comment: I always thought they were wider than all other parking slots so that women have it easier to park the car and not damage the surroundings. I am living in germany since 20 years and never realized that it is for security of the woman rather than the security of other cars since its a common prejudice that women can't drive or park. @glglgl [this](https://www.google.de/search?q=stvo+schild&rlz=1C1GGRV_deDE757DE757&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio26azq6fWAhWCXBoKHaHqAOoQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=1070#imgrc=1JOCQ79Blu9-fM:) is what the shield looks like

Comment: @ThorstenS. But if that sign exists, your claim that the StVO automatically applies if (...) doesn't make sense.

Comment: @glglgl Normal road and open access areas->StVO. Accessible from road, but barred area (gate, bar) -> own rules. But the owner of a *barred area* can say "Here is the StVO valid" (in fact they do it very often to have legal safety) and put exactly those signs up. You may think "I do not need to put up those signs, this is my ground" and you could be wrong. If your area could be considered part of the road environment, it is your responsibility to show that it ain't so. Look up the legal problem of *Besucherparkplätze* (visitor parking areas) because there I stumbled about this problem.

Answer (score 16):

Those parking places are designed so that woman do not have to walk alone in the night through the whole parking area. Especially parking decks can big big with several floors etc. and in the evening they are not very frequented and light conditions are more dim and dusky. Those places are usually close to the exit of the respective parking area (first floor, close to the vending machines, elevators etc.). 
They exist to minimize the chances of assaults on woman. However, this does not mean that we have a high rate of assaults on women here in germany. Rather, it displays the demand for very high security and - my opinion - it is primarily for people to feel safe. If it is a real improvement - I do not know if there are any numbers. But often it is important to feel safe for the society.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65710/discussion-on-answer-by-gnusper-reserved-parking-for-women-in-germany).